# Stripe subscriptions: why does it not prorate when auto-cancelling

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm planning to use Stripe to manage per-seat subscriptions for a SaaS product, and I'd like to allow customers to continue accessing the application in the event that payment fails (during the retry window), but ultimately cancel the subscription if all retries fail.

The scenario that none of Stripe's options seem to cover is:

1. Customer is automatically cancelled due to failed payments on all retries.
2. This leaves the Stripe customer in a state where the subscription is cancelled but the customer has an invoice for the full billing period in which they've just been cancelled. (Ideally this would automatically prorate but there doesn't seem to be any option to do that). Even worse this invoice is viewable/payable from the customer portal, even if I tell Stripe to mark this invoice uncollectible (the only other option from the settings).
3. Customer decides they want to reactivate. My app needs to create a new subscription for this customer.
4. I want the customer to now pay for the grace period where the product was available during the retry window / failed payments before they were cancelled. What's they best way to handle this?

I feel like there must be something obvious I'm missing, because all of the above leads down a path of tracking the previously unbilled usage in my application and then apply it as an additional charge if the customer attempts to reactivate (and also check Stripe to see whether they paid the last invoice from the cancelled subscription and account for overpayment in that case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're correct in that Stripe doesn't provide such feature(s) currently and you'll need to implement the logic to handle those scenarios.

> This leaves the Stripe customer in a state where the subscription is cancelled but the customer has an invoice for the full billing period in which they've just been cancelled. (Ideally this would automatically prorate but there doesn't seem to be any option to do that). Even worse this invoice is viewable/payable from the customer portal, even if I tell Stripe to mark this invoice uncollectible (the only other option from the settings).

If you don't want the customer to be able to pay the invoice, I would suggest listening for the `customer.subscription.deleted` event and [void the invoice(s)](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/void).
`

> I want the customer to now pay for the grace period where the product was available during the retry window / failed payments before they were cancelled. What's they best way to handle this?

My suggestion here would be to perform your own calculations for how much to charge the customer, and [add it as a one off invoice item when creating the Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-add_invoice_items).